# how to make css style !important inside ag-Grid's getRowStyle

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```html
getRowStyle(params) {
return { background-color: 'red !important'}
}
```

I know 'red !important' is not a valid. How to make background-color takes higher precedence over any other external styles?

Answer (score 0):

Property is invalid when it has hyphens in-between (`background-color`) change it to `backgroundColor` and it works great!

```
  getRowStyle: (params) => {
      return { backgroundColor: 'red !important'}
  },
```

[Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YhWKnpgn7N96KgAX?open=main.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be useful if you want to specify the background color for a specific cell.

```
{
  field: 'name',
  headerName: 'Name',
  cellStyle: (params) => {
    if (condition) {
      return { backgroundColor: 'red' };
    }
    return defaultStyle
  }
}
```